# Express js: Sequlize belongsto returns empty results

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js, belongs-to

I've two models

**SeatAllocation**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const SeatAllocation = sequelize.define('SeatAllocation', {
    id:{
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV1,
        primaryKey: true
    },   
    course_id: {
      type:DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull:false,
      references: {
        model: 'Courses', 
        key: 'id', 
     }
    },
    number_of_seats:{
      type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull:false
    },
    allocation_date:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false
    }
  },{
    timestamps: false
  }
  );

  SeatAllocation.associate = function (models) {
    models.SeatAllocation.belongsTo(models.Course, {
      onDelete: "CASCADE",  
      foreignKey:'course_id',
      targetKey:'id',
      as:'Courses'
    });
  };

  return SeatAllocation;
};
```

**Course**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Course = sequelize.define('Course', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV1,
        primaryKey: true
    },   
    name: {
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull:false
    },
    created_at:{
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull:false
    },
    updated_at:{
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull:false
    }

  },{
    timestamps: false
  }
  );

  Course.associate = function(models) {
    models.Course.hasMany(models.SeatAllocation,{
      foreignKey:'course_id',
      as:'Courses'
    });
  };


  return Course;
};
```

I am trying to get the all values from the seat allocations table along with the course details 
here is query i've tried so far

```
await models.SeatAllocation.findAll({
            include:[{
                model:models.Course,
                as:'Courses',
                all:true,
                required:true
            }]
        });
```

I am getting results however the `courses` object is missing on the result

Answer (score 0):

One possible oversight in SeatAllocation - what's up with `models.Task`? Don't you want to associate `SeatAllocation` with `Course`?  What does the generated SQL look like?

```
  SeatAllocation.associate = function (models) {
    models.Task.belongsTo(models.Course, {   
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
```

Comment: Sorry the model `Task` was actually a typo i've updated my question

Comment: I've tested something very similar and it works fine.  Can you execute the generated query in MySql Workbench?

Answer (score 0):

Make both assosiation in that way removing the models.Course use Course instead worked for me

```
Course.associate = function(models) {
    Course.hasMany(models.SeatAllocation,{
      foreignKey:'course_id',
      as:'Courses'
    });
  };
```

Comment: I didn't get your answer please add some more explanations

Comment: replace this portion  models.SeatAllocation.belongsTo by  SeatAllocation.belongsTo
cause you get the model variable in above but you are tring to pull it from models object